# Unable to install matplotlib in virtualenv on OS X (10.12.6)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm unable to install `matplotlib` using `pip` in a virtual environment on OS X (10.12.6). I am using the built-in system version of Python (`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`) which is the only installed version of Python 2.

I used `virtualenv` (version 15.1.0) to create the virtual environment. The `matplotlib` installation console output says that it could not build the `freetype` package, but I've installed this already using `brew` (it installed it in `/usr/local/Cellar/freetype`). Here's the installation console output:

```
(venv) $ pip install matplotlib
You are using pip version 7.0.3, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-2.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    IMPORTANT WARNING:
        pkg-config is not installed.
        matplotlib may not be able to find some of its dependencies
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: yes [2.0.2]
                    python: yes [2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)  [GCC
                            4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)]]
                  platform: yes [darwin]

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                     numpy: yes [not found. pip may install it below.]
                       six: yes [using six version 1.10.0]
                  dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.1]
               functools32: yes [functools32 was not found. It is required
                            forPython versions prior to 3.2]
              subprocess32: yes [subprocess32 was not found. It used  for Python
                            versions prior to 3.2 to improves functionality on
                            Linux and OSX]
                      pytz: yes [using pytz version 2017.2]
                    cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                   tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                            WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                 pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                            mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                            install it after matplotlib.]
                    libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                            be found. Using local copy.]
                  freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: yes [version 1.6.31]
                     qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                            found. Using local copy.]

    OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
               sample_data: yes [installing]
                  toolkits: yes [installing]
                     tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
            toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                    macosx: yes [installing, darwin]
                    qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                    qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
                   gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
                 gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                    gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                     tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                            Tk]
                     wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                       gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                       agg: yes [installing]
                     cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
                 windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

    OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: no
               ghostscript: no
                     latex: no
                   pdftops: no

    OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                      dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

    ============================================================================
                            * The following required packages can not be built:
                            * freetype

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/vx/3ts13s190k50b2gzt_6zyp0m0000gn/T/pip-build-HCJwzO/matplotlib
```

Comment: Basically, it appears as if in the virtual environment `pip` cannot find the path to the `brew`-installed `freetype` package which is `/usr/local/Cellar/freetype`. So I created a symlink to this package in `/usr/local/lib/python/2.7/site-packages`, but it still fails with the same message. I also created the same symlink in the virtual environment (`./venv/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freetype`), but it still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to solve this problem myself by installing and linking the `pkg-config` package using `brew`, then running `pip install matplotlib` in the virtual environment.